# Solving Ax = b with Eigen library in c++

Tags: c++, vector, std, eigen

I am trying to Solve Ax = b using least square method. I am using Eigen library to solve this. The input to my function are Matrix A (`vector<vector<double>>`) and RhS `vector<double>` b. I need to convert these to `Eigen::MatrixXd` and Eigen::VectorXd. I could convert b easily to `Eigen::VectorXd`. But I am not able to form the `Eigen::MatrixXd`.

Thanks for your answer in advance.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd ConvertToEigenMatrix(std::vector<std::vector<double>> data)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd eMatrix(data.size(), data[0].size());
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        eMatrix.row(i) = Eigen::VectorXd::Map(&data[i][0], data[0].size());
    return eMatrix;
}

std::vector<double> SolveUsingEigen(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A, const std::vector<double>& b)
{
    std::vector<double> ans;
    if (A.size() != b.size())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid output" << std::endl;
        return ans;
    }
    ans.reserve(b.size());
    Eigen::VectorXd b_eig = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd, Eigen::Unaligned>(const_cast<double*>(b.data()), b.size());
    Eigen::MatrixXd A_eig = ConvertToEigenMatrix(A);

    // Eigen::MatrixXd eig_ans = A_eig.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b_eig);

    Eigen::MatrixXd eig_ans = A_eig.bdcSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV).solve(b_eig);

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> v;

    for (int i = 0; i < eig_ans.rows(); ++i)
    {
        const double* begin = &eig_ans.row(i).data()[0];
        v.push_back(std::vector<double>(begin, begin + eig_ans.cols()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < eig_ans.rows(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < eig_ans.cols(); ++j)
            ans.push_back(v[i][j]);

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: First:  provide a complete example...Second:  test your approach by initializing your matrix with an initialization list instead of a loop...Third:  do some research, maybe starting here:  https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Eigen-Library-for-Matrix-Algebra-in-C

Comment: What is the problem ? Compilation error ? Bad results ?

Comment: I implemented your code: it works! The problem must be in the code not shown!

Comment: Have you read the doc page on [Solving linear least squares systems](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__LeastSquares.html)?

Comment: I think matrix initialization went fine. Ax = b is solved and Eigen library returns Matrix for x (even though it should be a vector in my case). My conversion of this matrix to std::vector was messed up.  I have to do something like this. std::vector<std::vector<double>> v;

 for (int i = 0; i < eig_ans.rows(); ++i)
 {
  const double* begin = &eig_ans.row(i).data()[0];
  v.push_back(std::vector<double>(begin, begin + eig_ans.cols()));
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < eig_ans.rows(); ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < eig_ans.cols(); ++j)
   ans.push_back(v[i][j]);

Comment: You "think matrix initialization went fine", but nobody else can be sure about that, since you neither pasted your complete code (check how/why to provide a [mcve]), nor say what actually went wrong with your code (as has been commented before).

Comment: Uploaded the full code.